# Google Pay - Stripe Getting error Google Pay failed with error: 412:

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I have implemented Google pay with stripe. Set up all things mentioned in documentation provided by stripe.[https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay] and get onGooglePayReady is true.
after that button press to pass client_secret to **presentForPaymentIntent**

```
client_secret = //fetch from backend

final GooglePayLauncher googlePayLauncher = new GooglePayLauncher(
                this,
                new GooglePayLauncher.Config(
                        GooglePayEnvironment.Test,
                        "IN",
                        "MerchantName"
                ),
                this::onGooglePayReady,
                this::onGooglePayResult
        );

googlePayButton.setOnClickListener(
                v -> googlePayLauncher.presentForPaymentIntent(client_secret)
        );
```

But getting error every time in **onGooglePayResult** result failed

**Google Pay failed with error: 412:**

Comment: You're probably running on a device that runs the Indian version of Google Pay; Stripe only supports the worldwide version (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user versus https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel )

Comment: @karllekko May be. but there must be some way for me to test for US and other countries in sandbox(test) mode?

Comment: Not really no, Google Pay can only be tested by running your app on a physical device with live card in the Google Pay wallet, unfortunately.